Problems with positioning vertical navbar
I am learning CSS and I am fed up with positioning, can somebody tell me, why vertical navbar overlaps horizontal? I want vertical to be sticky and link elements inside to be absolute to navbar, as you see i tried with div, but still first vertical link overlaps horizontal.
This is the code:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#hor {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
}

#hor a {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  position: static;
  padding: 2%;
}


/* #w{
                position: relative;
                left:  70px;
                bottom: 20px;
            } */

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vw;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

#ver {
  width: 10vw;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#ver a {
  display: inherit;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}

#ver a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
}
<div>
  <header> THIS IS HEADER</header>
  <nav id="hor" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="" style="background-color: aqua;">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="" style="background-color: orange;">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="" style="background-color: beige;">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="" style="background-color: gray;">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="" style="background-color: red;">LINK 1</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; width:10vw; height:10vw;">
  <nav id="ver">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">LINK 1</a>
  </nav>
</div>



How to position everything to make it vertical navbar sticky?
